# procedural mesh creation with blender script

Tags: blender

What is a clean way to create a procedural mesh in blender with a script? Ideally I'd like to create an empty mesh and start adding vertices and triangles, like this:

```
mesh = create_mesh()
a = mesh.add_vertex([0, 0, 0])
b = mesh.add_vertex([1, 0, 0])
c = mesh.add_vertex([1, 1, 0])
t = mesh.add_triangle(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Blenders [bmesh module](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) is designed for creating and editing mesh data, although you can also turn [python arrays into mesh data](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/addon_add_object.py).

You can find some examples included with blender, all addons are made using python, one helpful addon would be `add_mesh_extra_objects` which has several examples of creating different types of objects.

There is a [blender specific stackexchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com) where you will get more help with blender specific scripting. You should also find some existing examples there.